# Finding a point in a matrix representing an hemisphere using two angles

Tags: matrices, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates

I have a picture, in a matrix 301x301 format, that represents a fisheye view of the sky from a street (a circular image).

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJB5q.png)

This image is oriented, so that the point [0][150] points to North, [150][0] to the East etc. I also have two angles, which represent the sun position at a given time, respectively the Solar Zenith angle, and the Solar Azimuth Angle (e.g. 70° and 120°).

[description of the two angles provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfWzv.png)

As described in the image, I have to find the row and column of the pixel where more or less corresponds to the sun's position at that time.
The data available are the two angles, the radius of the circle representing the view and the length and height of the image. I can't really figure out the transformation that needs to be done, some advice would really be appreciated!

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: What is the cause of the vertical discontinuity line in the image?

Comment: There is a discontinuity because it is not really a 360° view of the area. I obtained this image from a wide cylindrical panorama of roughly 320°. I didn't think about it, but now I realise that it may influence the position of the sun as well, thanks for the observation.